# Change the name of Home page in Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint

is there any possibility to rename the home page in Sharepoint, and it still remaining Home Page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, after you rename the Home.aspx from library Site Pages, right click on item .aspx, click on More and on Check In.
[image]

Then right click on item .aspx and click on "Make homepage".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Rename" as in the displayed text in the page, or as in the filename of the page?

There are several ways to select a new home page (such as after renaming the file). SharePoint Designer, web services, PowerShell etc. See here: https://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2011/06/sharepoint-how-to-change-default-home.html